# Unable to retrieve html from a url when webscraping

Tags: python

I am trying to webscrape a url but I noticed when I do print on the request, it comes back with a blank. When I try a different website url, it prints the html. So to me it looks like a certain website url (can be any product url from that website) is not retrieving the html.

Does anybody know why this is and if I can try to get around this?

```
import requests

site_request = requests.get("https://www.screwfix.com/p/lap-13a-2-gang-sp-switched-socket-3-1a-2-outlet-type-a-usb-charger-white/4087p")

site_response = str(site_request.content)

print(site_response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site is rejecting requests that do not include valid user agent headers.

If you print the `site_request`, you'll see: `<Response [403]>` indicating a "Forbidden" response code.

If you include a valid user agent with your request, such as:

```
site_request = requests.get("<target_url>", headers={
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
})
```

You'll get a valid response.

Many sites reject such requests because they (usually) indicate trivial attempts at scraping, which they like to deter.